# How can I pass json to a python script via command line?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, command-line, python-3.6

I'd like to pass a simple set of name/value pairs to a python script via json on the command line.

```
$ curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 | python3.6 -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(23) Failed writing body
```

The json is simple:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit..."
}
```

And the goal is to assign variables like:

```
if json.load(sys.stdin)["title"] is not None:
    post_title = json.load(sys.stdin)["title"]
```

How can I accomplish this correctly?

Comment: `python3.6 -c 'print "anything"'` doesn't work. `print` is a function, not a statement, in Python 3.6.

Comment: doh! `curl -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 | python3.6 -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["title"])'` FTW. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parenthesis surrounding the argument to `print`:

```
python3.6 -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin))'
```

Comment: @DominikBrno, ...btw, you'll note this I marked this "Community Wiki" and am not getting points from it -- that's because answering this question was technically against the rules; see "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @DominikBrno, ...that said, because it's community-wiki, you're welcome to edit it if you think an example showing the working code (f/e, as done in your deleted answer) is a useful addition.